# Excessive CPU usage upon socket connection

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, connection

I have a client class which allows me to connect to ntrip client services (it is basically an http service).
This client allows me to connect to secure and non secure services. I am making use of the `javax.net` library.
Here is my code:

```
public class ntripClient_mng implements Runnable{
private static String nServer = "";
private static String nMountpoint = "";
private static String nUsername = "";
private static String nPassword = "";
private static int nPort = 0;
private boolean running = true;
private static boolean secure = false;

public static void main(String[] args){
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        if (args[i].equals("-a")){nServer = args[i+1];}
        if (args[i].equals("-p")){nPort = Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]);}
        if (args[i].equals("-u")){nUsername = args[i+1];}
        if (args[i].equals("-pw")){nPassword = args[i+1];}
        if (args[i].equals("-m")){nMountpoint = args[i+1];}
        if (args[i].equals("-s")){secure = args[i+1].matches("Y") ? true : false;}
    }

public ntripClient_mng(String server, int port, String user, String pass, String mount, String cType){
    nServer = server;
    nUsername = user;
    nPassword = pass;
    nMountpoint = mount;
    nPort = port;
    secure = cType.matches("Y") ? true : false;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    DataInputStream in = null;
    try {
        Socket s = null;
        SSLSocket sslSocket = null;
        // Creating Client Sockets
        if (secure){
            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            sslSocket = (SSLSocket)sslsocketfactory.createSocket(nServer,nPort);
        } else {
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(nServer, nPort);
            s = new Socket();
            s.connect(sockaddr, 10 * 1000);
        }
        if (true) {
            if (secure){
                sslSocket.setSoTimeout(15000);
                out = new DataOutputStream (sslSocket.getOutputStream());
                in = new DataInputStream (sslSocket.getInputStream());
            } else {
                s.setSoTimeout(15000);
                out = new DataOutputStream (s.getOutputStream());
                in = new DataInputStream (s.getInputStream());
            }

            // send a message to the server
            String requestmsg = GETrequest();
            out.write(requestmsg.getBytes());
            out.flush();
            while (running) {
                // receive a response
                byte[] b = new byte[1];
                if (first){
                  for (;;){
                    in.read(b);
                    if (b[0] == -45) break;
                  }
                  baos.write(b);
                  first = false;
                }
                for (;;){
                   in.read(b);
                   if (b[0] == -45){
                      break;
                   } else {
                      baos.write(b);
                   }
                }
                byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                decodeMessage(bytes);
                baos.reset();
                baos.write(b);
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} 
    catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} 
}}
```

The code is working fine, both for secure connection and non secure connection. However, what's bothering me is the excessive CPU usage when connecting to a non secure service. 
When i connect to a secure service, the CPU usage for one running thread is about 0.3%. When i connect to a non secure one, the CPU usage is about 30%.
Obviously there is a problem here but i can't understand what it is.

### EDIT

I have edited the code based on the suggestion in the answer.
Now i am reading the data, one byte at a time and using a stopping byte in order to stop the reading.
It may be the right way to do it, but the problem still remains.
while connecting to some services the CUP usage goes to 30%.

What might be the problem? Is it possible that there is an issue with the `javax.net` library? Could the problem be caused some how by the server itself?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not make use of httpclient or making use of nio classes that are available rather than creating socket boilerplate code of your own? See your if else that makes your code looks ugly

Comment: Don't, ever, use available(). It does not do what you think it does. And respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: @SMA I have tried `httpclient` once, was not working well for me. Maybe i'll give it a try again. What are nio classes?      @JB Nizet any constructive sugestions?

Comment: The 'constructive suggestion' is not to use `available()`. What happened theme you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. Actually i fixed it. Still using the `available()`.I have been told many times not to use it, but it is the only thing that is working for me.  Also tried to use `HttpURLConnection` but it was only working for secure ones, on a non secure connection i was getting error on server response (-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// send a message to the server
while (running)
{
    // receive a response
    if (secure)
    {
      // ... some code here
    }
    else
    {
      // !CHANGES HERE!
      byte[] bytes = readTillTimeout(in);
      decodeMessage(bytes);
    }
}
```

I usually just read byte-per-byte and add them together using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

When there are no more bytes available, the read method will lock-up for a small time (the `setSoTimeout(...)` which you specified). If nothing is received within that delay, then it will throw a `SocketTimeoutException`, meaning that the end of your data is reached.

```
private byte[] readTillTimeout(DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
    try
    {
        int input = in.read();
        if (input == -1) throw new IllegalStateException("disconnected");
        baos.write((byte)input);
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException ste)
    {
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

In my opinion the `setSoTimeout(value)` shouldn't be more than 2 seconds really.

I used this approach in many many applications.
I just tested this with the code that you specified. Like you said, before it was at 30% CPU usage. Now it's about ~0%.

## EDIT: (Because EJP downvoted my answer)

We're having a difficult audience today.

Yes, it's true a timeout isn't always a good solution. Sometimes you want to read until a specific character is found for example. A very popular approach for communication with industrial machines is to make each message start with an `STX`(0x02) byte and to make it end with an `ETX`(0x03) byte.

Here's a code sample that uses a `startByte` and `stopByte` input.

```
private byte[] readMessage(DataInputStream in, byte startByte, byte stopByte) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
    try
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            int input = in.read();
            if (input == -1) throw new IllegalStateException("disconnected");
            if (input == startByte) break;
        }
        
        for(;;)
        {
            int input = in.read();
            if (input == -1) throw new IllegalStateException("disconnected");
            if (input == stopByte) break;
            baos.write((byte)input);
        }
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException ste)
    {
      return null;
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: You are making the unwarranted assumption that all parts of a message arrive without blocking. Ths might work for a while but there is nothing written down in any specification that says so.

Comment: @EJP Indeed, it depends on the specification. And in some cases each interraction is ended with a disconnect. In other cases each message is delimited with specific characters (e.g. STX `0x02` and ETX `0x03`) or has a specific format (including a frame header with message length field). - But that's out of scope for this question. - Look at the original code. There's no check there neither.

Comment: In this case, once i am connected to the service the data is flowing constantly. meaning, there are no disconnections. maybe i'll try to implement @bvdb example as well.

Comment: Receiving an application message depends 100% on correct implementaton of the application protocol, and there is no case in which that can be accomplished correctly via use of `available()`. Answer remains incorrect.

Comment: @EJP It's not because an answer is incorrect, that you should flag it for deletion. There's no porn in it, is there ?

Comment: @EJP ... and because `available()` is incorrect, my answer does not use `available()`. That's exactly the point of my answer.

Comment: @bvdb I have used your suggestion and made changes to the code, see the edit in my question. The problem still remains. Any advise?

Comment: @DanyLavrov - Strange, I'm not having the performance issue. I would get rid of the `byte[] b = new byte[1];` just read byte-per-byte. e.g. `byte b = in.read();` (ps: I did get the performance issue with your original code though)

Comment: problem solved. apparently the server would respond with a message that i didn't checked before (didn't think this message would pop up). everything works now, thank you.